# Any idea on how to compute this integral?

Tags: integration, expected-value, characteristic-functions

I am trying to compute an integral
$$\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{k}^T\Sigma\boldsymbol{k} + i (\boldsymbol{\mu}-\boldsymbol{x})} V(\boldsymbol{x}) \boldsymbol{k} d\boldsymbol{x} d\boldsymbol{k},$$
where the $\boldsymbol \mu$ and $\boldsymbol \Sigma$ are parameters of a multi-variate Normal distribution.
I am expecting the result equals to $0$, but cannot find out how to get it.
Could anyone give me some help? Thanks. :)

Comment: What is $V(x)$?

Comment: $\int_R e^{-k^2_i}k_idk_i=0$ - you integrate the odd function ($f(-k)=-f(k)$) over $R$

Comment: @Svyatoslav if V(x) is an odd function, it feels like the result should be zero, but how to compute this integration rigorously? :)

Comment: @ReedeeAlexander : $d\boldsymbol{x}$ runs over $\mathbb R^n$ and so does $d\boldsymbol{k}\,.$ You can pull out of the $d\boldsymbol{k}$-integral everything that does not depdend on $\boldsymbol{k}$.

Comment: $$\mathbf{k}=\vec{e_i}k_i\,;\,\,\int_{R^n}e^{-\mathbf{k}^2}\mathbf{k}d\mathbf{k}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-k_n^2}dk_n.. \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-k_1^2}(\vec{e_1}k_1+...\vec{e_n}k_n)dk_1 $$
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(k)kdk= \,\,(k=-t) \,\,\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(-t)(-t)d(-t)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(-t)tdt=-I$$ $$I=-I\,\,\Rightarrow \,\, I=0$$